# Why can't I apply the same logic?

Tags: circuit-analysis, diodes

it's difficult to understand the exercise, because I can't apply the same logic as the exercise. To solve it I have to find the Total chains one and two. However, when I did exercise a I managed to find the answer, I applied the same logic as in other exercise b, but it is wrong, because the behavior is that of a closed circuit and the only difference in the circuit is the position of the resistors (values) are exchanged. , I don't understand why I can't apply the same logic as in exercise a.[image]

Comment: Closed brings a ground (0V) point into play.  Open means that 0V connection is not applicable and you only have current flowing between 3V and -3V.  It is the same logic in the sense that you still apply the current summing law and V=IR; just different points to flow between and different values for R.

Comment: It isn't clear what "logic" you're applying here. For case "a", you found the current in the resistors, but that isn't what the question is asking for. Show us you're reasoning and maybe we can show where you're going astray.

Comment: @Dave Tweed
 
A) IT=I2 = 1/3 mA..... Vout=3 -( 12k * 1/3 mA ) = -0,996 v 

B) IT=I2 = 1/3 mA..... Vout=3 -(6k * 1/3 mA ) =1 v

My question is because in the exercise it is considered as an open key and in Exercise B it is considered as a closed key, and I applied the calculation in both situations as an open key, I just don't understand why it is wrong, exercise b

Comment: A perfect diode conducts electricity if the voltage of the positive side (anode) is higher than the voltage of the negative side (cathode). If the left diode was missing (open circuit) in both circuits, what do you think would be the voltages in both circuits?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but I'm still not following your logic. But if you consider D1 as a "closed key", what does this tell you about the voltage at its anode -- and also about the current in the upper resistor and the value of V? This allows you to compute the current in the lower resistor, which is also the current in D2. Knowing these two currents, KCL gives you the net current through D1.

Answer (score 0):

You are sooo close to the answer. The logic that you applied is correct. Now, just look at the reduced circuit b). The switch is closed, pulling zero volts to the middle node. So what is the voltage at out relative to ground?